# c++ template template : cannot access private member

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to work with Template Template parameters in C++, with the famous Stack example :

However I get acompilation error in the code below. My understanding is that `'Stack<T2, CONT2>'` and `'Stack<T, CONT>'` are the same class so 'container' is accecible in '`Stack<T, CONT>::operator = ( const Stack<T2, CONT2>& rhs )'`

could you help me? is there something specific I should pay attention to when working with Template Template parameters?

```
template <typename T,
    template < typename ELEM, typename ALLOC = std::allocator< ELEM > > class CONT = std::deque >
class Stack
{
    CONT<T> container ;

public :
    Stack() {} ;
    template <typename T2>
    void push_back ( const T2& elem ) ;
    bool isEmpty (void ) const ;

    template <typename T2, 
        template < typename ELEM2, typename  = std::allocator< ELEM2 > > class CONT2 >
        Stack<T, CONT>& operator = (const Stack<T2,CONT2>& rhs ) ;

    void push_back (T const& elem ) {
        container.push_back (elem) ;
    };
    T operator [] (size_t i ) const  ;
    T& operator [] ( size_t i ) ;
};

template <typename T, template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC > class CONT >
T Stack<T, CONT>::operator [] (size_t i ) const {
    return container [i] ;
}

template <typename T, template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC > class CONT >
T& Stack<T, CONT>::operator[] ( size_t i )
{
    return container [i] ;
}

template <typename T, template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC > class CONT >
template <typename T2, template < typename , typename > class CONT2 >
    Stack<T, CONT>& Stack<T, CONT>::operator = ( const Stack<T2, CONT2>& rhs )
{
    if ( this->container != rhs.container ) // ERROR !!!
    {
        if ( this->container.size() == 0 )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < rhs.container.size() ; ++i )
            {
                (*this).container.push_back( (T) rhs[i] ) ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < this->container.size() ; ++i )
            {
                (*this)[i] = rhs[i] ;
            }
        }
    }

    return *this ;
}

int main()
{
    Stack<int> stk ;
    Stack<double> stkd ;

    stk.push_back(10) ;
    stk.push_back(5) ;

    stkd = stk ;

    int st = stk[1] ;

    return 0;

}
```

the compilation error is :

```
>e:\project2\project2\source.cpp(46): error C2248: 'Stack<T>::container' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Stack<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          e:\project2\project2\source.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'Stack<T>::container'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>          ]
1>          e:\project2\project2\source.cpp(75) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Stack<T> &Stack<T>::operator =<int,std::deque>(const Stack<int> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=double
1>          ]
1>          e:\project2\project2\source.cpp(75) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Stack<T> &Stack<T>::operator =<int,std::deque>(const Stack<int> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=double
1>          ]
```

Comment: No, `Stack<int>` and `Stack<double>` ara different classes.

Comment: Stack is not a class to begin with. It's a class template.

Comment: add this : `template<class Other> friend class Stack<Other>;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A template is a blueprint the compiler uses to construct the actual classes. So whenever you use a template class with a specific parameter the compiler creates a class based on the provided blueprint.

Let's check out this (extremely simplified) example:

```
template < typename T >
class Test {
    T member:
};
```

When you now create a `Test<int>` and a `Test<double>` the compiler will generate two classes like these:

```
class Test/* some information comes here, so that the compiler can differentiate different Test classes */
{
    int member;
};

class Test/* again some additional information */
{
    double member;
};
```

Although they look quite similar, they are not the same. The same thing applies to your `Stack`. `stkd` and `stk` have different types and can therefore not be assigned to one another.

---

To fix this you can make every compiler generated instance of the template a friend of each other like so:

```
template <typename T,
    template < typename ELEM, typename ALLOC = std::allocator< ELEM > > class CONT = std::deque > 
class Stack {
    /* ... */

public :

    /* ... */

    template<class Other, 
        template < typename elem, typename allod = std::allocator< elem > > class cont >  
        friend class Stack;

    /* ... */ };
```

Note that this won't allow you to compare the different containers so you need to find another way to prevent self assignments (if someone here has a good idea feel free to add it). Here is the modified assignment operator:

```
template <typename T, template <typename ELEM, typename ALLOC > class CONT >
template <typename T2, template < typename , typename > class CONT2 >
    Stack<T, CONT>& Stack<T, CONT>::operator = ( const Stack<T2, CONT2>& rhs )
{

    /* self assignment check needed */
    {
        if ( this->container.size() == 0 )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < rhs.container.size() ; ++i )
            {
                (*this).container.push_back( (T) rhs[i] ) ;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < this->container.size() ; ++i )
            {
                (*this)[i] = rhs[i] ;
            }
        }
    }

    return *this ;
}
```

Comment: how to fix it would be nice too

Comment: @sp2danny Here you are.

Comment: Hmm, I don´t see what this self assignment stuff is about? T1 = T2 will be handled by the default assignment operator and not by the template overload and it is reasonable to not qualify T1 != T2 as self assignment independently of the content of T1 and T2, isn´t it?